# ASP.NET self host error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, self-hosting

I'm trying to get ASP.NET Web API self host running. I keep getting this error.

How do I resolve this?

Assuming assembly reference `Microsoft.Owin, Version=2.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' matches assembly`Microsoft.Owin, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. You may need to supply runtime policy (CS1701)

Here is my simple start up script.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (WebApp.Start<TestApi> ("http://*:9090/")) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("server started");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you solve this and how?

Answer (score 0):

The two assemblies differ in release and/or version number. For unification to occur, you must specify directives in the application's .config file, and you must provide the correct strong name of an assembly, as demonstrated in the following example code:

```
using System.Reflection;
[assembly:AssemblyVersion("1.0")]
public class A {
   public void M1() {}
}
```

OR:

Perhaps you need a binding redirect in your .config

```
<configuration>
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.2.0" newVersion="2.0.2.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.2.0" newVersion="2.0.2.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: But I only have one assembly referenced through Nuget. How do I find where the other reference is coming from?

Comment: Yeah, I have a binding redirect. Its is build time warning. Looking to get rid of that warning.